# Ember.js flat route structure vs. mess in root templates dir

Tags: ember.js, ember-rails

Using flat route (if a view has to be displayed in a separate view) structure solves many problems and helps to avoid unnecessary code, but all templates in a root template dir are more than mess:

For example:

(using ember-rails)

```
AddressBook.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'contacts'
  @resource 'contact', path: '/contacts/:contact_id'
  @resource 'contactNew', path: '/contacts/new'
  @resource 'contactEdit', path: '/contacts/:contact_id/edit'
```

all templates for routes defined above have to be in the root directory. With more routes it'd be more than a problem to maintain it.

Is it possible to keep templates in order? Or maybe something has changed when it comes to Ember router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using some kind of Handlebars pre-compiler which is getting the template name from the path. (I've never used rails, so I don't know if that's built into Ember-rails.) If that's the case, I think you have two options.

1. You could attempt to modify/configure the pre-compiler so that it takes the template name from somewhere other than the path. I don't know which one you're using, so I can't really give you details.
2. You can change the template that the route renders. You could use the [render](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) method of `Route`, or you could defined the view for the route and change the `layoutName` property.

Personally, I would highly suggest taking advantage of nested routes, as they offer many other benefits besides template organization. But if you really don't want to, look up documentation on your pre-compiler and try option number 1. You might be able to come up with something clever.

EDIT: With Ember-Rails, option 1 is probably the best. I don't know anything about Ruby, but I'm pretty sure everything you need is in [template.rb](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/blob/master/lib/ember/handlebars/template.rb).

Comment: Yup we're using a pre-compiler that comes from `ember-rails` gem. But as for nested routes, have you seen this article: http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ember-routing-the-when-and-why-of-nesting?

Comment: He's not saying that flat routes are better, he's saying that they're better suited for certain situations. But Ember is built around hierarchies; templates, routes, controllers, views, etc. And since that article was written, there have been many bugfixes and many new features added to eliminate boilerplate in nested objects. I think it's safe to say that in most situations, you'd actually write _more_ code and boilerplate with a flat structure.

Comment: Could you give some links to articles / posts that describe updated router / routing in Ember and how much more code and boilerplate I can avoid not using flat structure?

Comment: Well as of [1.5.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html), routes inherit their parent model, which is really nice. But nested routes also allow [event bubbling](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) and make using the [loading and error](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) substates much easier to use.

Comment: OK, got it. Were're going to upgrade to newest stable Ember / Ember-Data in the following weeks so we'll take a closer look at our routes. Thanks.